# Want to instantiate a ruby class using a private constructor from factory

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am used to c#/.net, so I come form a typesafe background.  I am using Ruby. I want to create a class (ClassA) that has a private (I'd settle for protected if I need to) constructor.  The reason being, I want to create a Factory (FactoryModule::create) that controls the instantiation of all ClassA objects.  I realize this is not fool-proof(?) in Ruby, but at least the code will be self-documenting in that it will be obvious based on the code and the tests that ClassA must be instantiated via the FactoryModule::create method.  In the ModuleFactory::create method, I tried changing the visibility of the ClassA constructor to public, instantiating the object, then changing the visibility back to private but A) I received errors and B) it is sloppy and not thread-safe.  Any thoughts?

**Update Answer:**

https://gist.github.com/gangelo/5551902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Answer**

Including this module in my class, protects Klass.new from being called:

```
module ProtectedConstructor
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.module_eval do
      class << self
        protected :new

        def inherited(klass)
          klass.module_eval do
            def self.new(*args); super; end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Instantiating Klass via protected constructor, takes place as such:

```
Klass.send(:new, *params...*)
```

Credit for this solution can be found: [here](http://www.shaneharvie.com/2007/08/making-constructors-protected-in-ruby.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a private (or protected) method from outside of your class, you can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send). So in your factory you could have something like:

```
instance = ClassA.send(:create)
```

Comment: thanks dude, but I needed to protect, ultimately, Klass.new. I did use that to call Klass.send(:new, params) which helped me.

Comment: Sorry - I misread your question as stating that you were defining `create` as private, and using that for instantiation.

Comment: no worries; seems to be going around lately; perhaps I'm the "pompous ass".